# Como que eu faço para o vídeo parar quando eu fechar o Modal?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, twitter-bootstrap

Quando eu fecho o modal o vídeo continua reproduzindo, como eu faço para o vídeo parar quando eu fechar o modal?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/soB_zeZhVc0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Talvez isso lhe ajude: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/299376/8063

Comment: Se você não usar a api do youtube para poder ter acesso aos controles do vídeo, uma possibilidade é você guardar o src do vídeo em um data-src e quando o modal abrir, você seta o src do iframe. Quando fechar, você remove o src do iframe. Não é a melhor alternativa, pois não é uma funcionalidade de pause.

Recomendo a leitura da documentação e trabalhar com a api: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=pt-br#pauseVideo

Answer (score 1):

Como o método `stopVideo` sugerido nos comentários não está mais funcionando (não funcionou para mim, o navegador acusa método não encontrado), porque provavelmente a API do youtube deve ter mudado ou algo do tipo, aqui está uma versão que funcionou para o meu caso.

Na url do vídeo é necessário informar os parametros `?rel=0&modestbranding=1&fs=0&controls=0&autoplay=1&showinfo=0&version=3&enablejsapi=1`, sendo que os mais importantes são `version` e `enablejsapi`.

Exemplo:

```
<iframe id="meuVideo" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/video_id?rel=0&modestbranding=1&fs=0&controls=0&autoplay=1&showinfo=0&version=3&enablejsapi=1" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Abaixo está a função que pode iniciar ou parar o vídeo, que no caso está no clique do botão `PAUSE`, você pode alterar para o clique do botão de fechar a sua modal.

```js
    <script>
        $('#play').click(function() {
            $('#meuVideo').each(function(){ 
                var frame = document.getElementById("meuVideo");
                frame.contentWindow.postMessage(
                    '{"event":"command","func":"playVideo","args":""}', 
                    '*'); 
            });
        });
    
        $('#pause').click(function() {
            $('#meuVideo').each(function(){ 
                var frame = document.getElementById("meuVideo");
                frame.contentWindow.postMessage(
                    '{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}',
                    '*'); 
            });
        });
    </script>
```

```html
    <button id="play">PLAY</button>
    <button id="pause">PAUSE</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu estava com o mesmo problema, resolvi desta forma.

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var $iframes = $(e.target).find('iframe');
    $iframes.each(function(index, iframe) {
      $(iframe).attr("src", $(iframe).attr('src'));
    });
 });
```